# Interval Notation: Specific Order or no?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

If the question asks for domain in interval notation, would [1, -6] be incorrect? In other words, does proper interval notation dictate that it must go from least to greatest?

And if the question did not ask specifically for the domain in interval notation, would [1, -6] then be correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately it depends on what is the definition of $[a,b]$.

I use the definition of

$$[a,b]=\{x \in \mathbb{R}| a \leq x \leq b \}$$

Hence $[1,-6]=\emptyset \neq [-6,1]$.

Remark: If you check out the interval (Mathematics) on wikipedia, this convention is used as well.